# Trouble creating vertical trendline on clustered bar chart in Excel 2016

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have 2 columns of data in Excel 2016. Col. A is a list of states and Col. B is a percentage. I've successfully made a clustered bar chart (vertically oriented list of bars) with A as the Y axis and B as the X axis.  Now I'd like to add a vertical line showing the median. I've been trying to follow the instructions on this [page](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/add-vertical-line-excel-chart/) in the section entitled "How to add vertical line to Excel bar chart" but I'm stuck on Step 6.

It says "The new data series is now added to your bar chart (two orange bars). Right click it and pick Change Series Chart Type in the pop-up menu." But I can only select one of the 2 new bars at a time, not both as shown in the image. After than, even if I select only 1 bar, step 7 says to choose "Scatter with Straight Lines" for my new series, but that option isn't available (maybe because I only selected one of the 2 bars?).

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?  Or, alternatively, is there another way to do this?